# how to use IndexedDB in the background service_worker of Chrome Extension Manifest 3？

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

we could use chrome.storage.local in the background service_worker of manifest version 3,
but how could we use IndexedDB in service_worker ?

Comment: It just works. Simply call `indexedDB.open`.

Comment: thank you. but it seems we can't use indexedDB both in the service_worker and js of options_page, or alert error : "Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found." :(

Comment: @user1566268: try adding either "storage" or "unlimitedStorage" permissions in your manifest, as suggested in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71452309/3705191